# Regex in Atom.io search field

Tags: regex

So, for example, I have this list:

```
10text
11text
12text
13text
14text
15text
16text
17text
18text
19text
```

Now I need to copy this and make it all into the `20-29` and `30-39` range with a Regex.

So only the very first `1` needs to be changed into a `2` and a `3` etc.

I can't seem to figure out what the regex is.

I tried: `1.text` `1*text`

Now I have been doing some reading and probably because it ain't in my native language it is still magic to me.

http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/regexe.html

https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

http://2017.compciv.org/guide/topics/end-user-software/atom/how-to-use-regex-atom.html

[Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info

**What was I hoping for**

When I fill in this in the search field:

`1*text`

and this in the replace field:

`2*text`

then on pressing change all the list becomes

```
20text
21text
22text
23text
24text
25text
26text
27text
28text
29text
```

Comment: Please include your expected output, but in any case it seems that a pure regex solution won't give you what you want anyway.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Updated my question please have a look. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you are trying to do here, but if you want to convert `1xtext` to `2xtext`, then try searching for this pattern:

```
^1
```

and then replace with just `2`.  Or, more generally, to match something like `(1xtext)` you could try using the pattern `\b1`, and again replace with `2`.

Comment: Does this mean that there can't be any content in front of the `1xtext` so lets say when it is encapsulated with `(1xtext)`?
Atom.io is not responding to the regex.